# Getting an error Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val with okhttp

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

Using response.body() gives me an error of "Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val" i tried removing ? but nothing works the error is in body()

```
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string();

            println(body)
            println("Sucees")
```

Answer (score 27):

It looks like you're using OkHttp 4.0.0.

The [`response.body()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Response.kt#L202-L207) function has been deprecated. Instead, you need to access the body as a val, like this:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body?.string();

            println(body)
            println("Sucees")
}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yes that solved that issue which  i thought wascausing me this problem of not bein able to connect to my local host  tho am able to connect to an online one

Comment: For more details, see this upgrade guide: http://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/