# Kotlin | API request with okhttp

Tags: android, api, class, kotlin, okhttp

Solution:

````
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var playerStats: PlayerStats

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Picasso.get().load("https://...../....../example.png").into(Viewer)
        var PlayerName: String = ""

        fun fetchJson() {
            val url = "https://my.api.site/example/"
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                var mainHandler = Handler(this@MainActivity.getMainLooper())
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    mainHandler.post {
                        val body = response.body()?.string()
                        if (body == null) return@post
                        println(body)

                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        playerStats = gson.fromJson(body, PlayerStats::class.java)
                        println(playerStats)

                        // TODO Now you can access to your view and set every thing to textView
                        textView.text = playerStats.username
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    println("API execute failed")
                }
            })
        }

        buttonGO.setOnClickListener {
            PlayerName = editText.text.toString()
            fetchJson()
            if (PlayerName == null || PlayerName.trim() == "") {
                println("please input data, input cannot be blank")
            } else {
                Picasso.get().load("https://...../...../" + PlayerName + ".png")
                    .into(Viewer)
                textView.setText(PlayerName).toString()
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

I have this code for my api request and it works when I use **debugger**.

I can see the results in the PlayerStats class but now I have a problem.

But on the **`MainActivity.class`** this `function` don't work:

```
val url = "https://api.example.com/..../"
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
val client = OkHttpClient()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        val body = response?.body?.string()
        println(body)
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val PlayerStats = gson.fromJson(body, PlayerStats::class.java)
        println(PlayerStats)
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        println("API execute failed")
    }
})
```

**Stats.class**:

```
class PlayerStats(val username: String  , val level: Double )
```

I need a way to get access to the `val username` / `val level` from `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity(val mystats: PlayerStats) : AppCompatActivity(){
```

> Not works, because of the zero arguments.

If I try to fix:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    var myStats: Stats? = null
//..
}
```

The IDE say it needs a `safe call` or a `non-null` asserted call but if I try this with the `non-null` asserted call the application crash and i get this error:

> 2020-03-05 18:58:02.803 23276-23276/my.example.package
>   E/AndroidRuntime: 
>       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: my.example.package, PID: 23276
>       kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>         at my.example.package.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:31)
>         at my.example.package.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:68)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>         at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

With the `safe call` I get `null` as output

---

**Full code:**

MainActivity.class:

```
package my.example.package

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Picasso.get().load("https://...../....../example.png").into(Viewer)
        var PlayerName: String = ""
        fun fetchJson() {
            val url = "https://my.api.site/example/"
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    val body = response?.body?.string()
                    println(body)
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    val PlayerStats = gson.fromJson(body, PlayerStats::class.java)
                    println(PlayerStats)
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    println("API execute failed")
                }
            })
        }

        buttonGO.setOnClickListener {
            PlayerName = editText.text.toString()
            fetchJson()
            if (PlayerName == null || PlayerName.trim() == "") {
                println("please input data, input cannot be blank")
            } else {
                Picasso.get().load("https://...../...../" + PlayerName + ".png")
                    .into(Viewer)
                textView.setText(PlayerName).toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerStats.class:

```
package my.example.package
class PlayerStats(val username: String  , val level: Double )
```

Comment: for example get them in a value or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this with your code:

````
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var playerStats: PlayerStats

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Picasso.get().load("https://...../....../example.png").into(Viewer)
        var PlayerName: String = ""

        fun fetchJson() {
            val url = "https://my.api.site/example/"
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                var mainHandler = Handler(this@MainActivity.getMainLooper())
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    mainHandler.post {
                        val body = response.body()?.string()
                        if (body == null) return@post
                        println(body)

                        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                        playerStats = gson.fromJson(body, PlayerStats::class.java)
                        println(playerStats)

                        // TODO Now you can access to your view and set every thing to textView
                        textView.text = playerStats.username
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    println("API execute failed")
                }
            })
        }

        buttonGO.setOnClickListener {
            PlayerName = editText.text.toString()
            fetchJson()
            if (PlayerName == null || PlayerName.trim() == "") {
                println("please input data, input cannot be blank")
            } else {
                Picasso.get().load("https://...../...../" + PlayerName + ".png")
                    .into(Viewer)
                textView.setText(PlayerName).toString()
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: thx very much...

one little problem at `val body = response.body()?.string()` the .body has an error: `Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val `

Comment: IDE suggests to replace `val body = response.body()?.string()` with `val body = response.body?.string()` or to replace the usage of `body(): ResponseBody? in whole project

Comment: i googled the error but the only thing i found is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913085/getting-an-error-using-body-responsebody-is-an-error-moved-to-val-with-ok

Comment: It's not important. It depends on your okHttp version. If the answer was useful, please mark it as answer

Comment: found a solution i removed the "()" after body

Comment: hey can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607465/api-request-okhttp-api-request-via-okhttp-with-two-objects